# Get color of the task bar in Microsoft Project (VBA)

Tags: vba, project, ms-project

It's well known in Microsoft Project VBA how to change the color of a task bar using typically:

GanttBarFormatEx TaskID:= CurrentId, GanttStyle:=7, MiddleColor:= myColor

However... i'm looking for a property to get the actual color instead than changing it. I looked into the Microsoft Project VBA reference but failed to found any information.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vincent, Unlike Excel Project doesn't expose the ability to read format colors be they in text or for Gantt Bars. What I normally do is use a indirect method which is to uncover the criteria that set the color and thereby deduce the displayed color. If the color was set by the whim of the user, you're stuck, but normally that user set some criteria (e.g. field value or combination of field values) and you can test for that.

Comment: Thx. Therefore i’m stuck…

Comment: Vincent, thanks for the check. Maybe you're not stuck. A couple of years ago I had a guy with Project file that had tons of color formatting and he wanted to export it to Excel with all the formatting. It took some back and forth but eventually I nailed him down on what criteria he used for the formatting. I wrote the export macro and he recently told me he still uses it. So, if you can, press a little harder. There is normally some thinking behind "whim".